# How to read this file,with skipping some lines using Python?

Tags: python

I need to skip 47 lines of the file(header and so on),then read this

```
 4.163186002791e+04  3.578830331359e+04  3.076496349687e+04  2.644671278966e+04  2.273458304119e+04 
 1.954349752908e+04  1.680032112209e+04  1.444218412726e+04  1.241504140604e+04  1.067243373686e+04 
 9.174423035938e+03  7.886677033340e+03  6.779682426302e+03  5.828068476394e+03  5.010025548360e+03 
 1.737988920100e+03  1.284332855871e+03  1.104060538508e+03  8.158747205330e+02  7.013564117662e+02 
 6.029121922103e+02  5.182858606802e+02  4.455379022877e+02  2.433020871700e+02  2.091515701348e+02 
 1.797945089525e+02  1.545580816278e+02  1.328639052196e+02  9.818329499070e+01  7.255514128762e+01 
 5.361653963401e+01  4.609078195788e+01  3.962135930423e+01  3.406000172766e+01  2.927925083995e+01 
 2.516953864546e+01  2.163667639887e+01  1.859969593339e+01  1.598899398582e+01  1.374473698894e+01 
 1.181548977143e+01  1.015703673713e+01  8.731368506527e+00  7.505810795983e+00  6.452275569743e+00 
 5.546617302183e+00  4.768079596776e+00  4.098819479081e+00  3.523498461194e+00  3.028931005477e+00 
 2.603782330822e+00  2.238308635635e+00  1.924133783786e+00  1.654057335509e+00  1.421889523591e+00 
 1.222309392724e+00  1.050742850800e+00  9.032578372386e-01  7.764742057598e-01  6.674862562538e-01 
 5.737961402745e-01  4.932566139141e-01  3.133421372728e-01  2.315524554696e-01  1.990511474577e-01 
 1.711118080085e-01  1.470941072881e-01  1.264475938317e-01  1.086990789815e-01  9.344179207682e-02 
 8.032605785014e-02  6.905128236880e-02  5.935906385039e-02  5.102727046220e-02
```

possibly as list,and then again skip 21 lines and read the part of the file in same format as presented above.
Firstly my idea was something like this:

```
from itertools import islice
n=15
with open('91_FULLMERGED.edi') as f:
    lines_after_48 = f.readlines()[48:]
    while True:
        next_15_lines = list(islice(lines_after_48, n))
        if not next_15_lines:
            break
```

But that is not working.

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/EDIs$ python k1.py
```

It is just standing still in terminal.

How to solve this?

Comment: Please try to explain yourself better, what exception do you get? or if you dont get an exception, what is the problem?

Comment: have you tried to print a statement inside your conditions? you're not asking to print anything in this code...

Comment: @Dot_Py Now I have added print next_15_lines,it is just printing numbers non-stop on the screen.

Comment: i think it'll do that untill you dont have 15 next lines... try creating a file with 31 lines and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

I use the csv reader cause the format is csv with delimiter '  '. At first I just skipped 47 lines by just next(f,None). Afterwards the csv module is making the trick. If you want to output as a file you can just use the csv writer. You can uncomment the code if you want to remove the empty strings from the output list. But then the output to the file is not similar to the input. It depends on how you wanna use the data.

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for i in range(47):
        next(f, None)
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ')
    values = list(reader)

# if you want to remove the ''
#for idx, val in enumerate(values):
#    values[idx] = [x for x in values[idx] if x != '']

print values

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for line in values:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

**Output to screen**

```
[['4.163186002791e+04', '', '3.578830331359e+04', '', '3.076496349687e+04', '', '2.644671278966e+04', '', '2.273458304119e+04'],
['1.954349752908e+04', '', '1.680032112209e+04', '', '1.444218412726e+04', '', '1.241504140604e+04', '', '1.067243373686e+04'],
['9.174423035938e+03', '', '7.886677033340e+03', '', '6.779682426302e+03', '', '5.828068476394e+03', '', '5.010025548360e+03'],
['1.737988920100e+03', '', '1.284332855871e+03', '', '1.104060538508e+03', '', '8.158747205330e+02', '', '7.013564117662e+02'],
['6.029121922103e+02', '', '5.182858606802e+02', '', '4.455379022877e+02', '', '2.433020871700e+02', '', '2.091515701348e+02'],
['1.797945089525e+02', '', '1.545580816278e+02', '', '1.328639052196e+02', '', '9.818329499070e+01', '', '7.255514128762e+01'],
['5.361653963401e+01', '', '4.609078195788e+01', '', '3.962135930423e+01', '', '3.406000172766e+01', '', '2.927925083995e+01'],
['2.516953864546e+01', '', '2.163667639887e+01', '', '1.859969593339e+01', '', '1.598899398582e+01', '', '1.374473698894e+01'],
['1.181548977143e+01', '', '1.015703673713e+01', '', '8.731368506527e+00', '', '7.505810795983e+00', '', '6.452275569743e+00'],
['5.546617302183e+00', '', '4.768079596776e+00', '', '4.098819479081e+00', '', '3.523498461194e+00', '', '3.028931005477e+00'],
['2.603782330822e+00', '', '2.238308635635e+00', '', '1.924133783786e+00', '', '1.654057335509e+00', '', '1.421889523591e+00'],
['1.222309392724e+00', '', '1.050742850800e+00', '', '9.032578372386e-01', '', '7.764742057598e-01', '', '6.674862562538e-01'],
['5.737961402745e-01', '', '4.932566139141e-01', '', '3.133421372728e-01', '', '2.315524554696e-01', '', '1.990511474577e-01'],
['1.711118080085e-01', '', '1.470941072881e-01', '', '1.264475938317e-01', '', '1.086990789815e-01', '', '9.344179207682e-02'],
['8.032605785014e-02', '', '6.905128236880e-02', '', '5.935906385039e-02', '', '5.102727046220e-02']]
```

**Output to file output.txt**

```
4.163186002791e+04  3.578830331359e+04  3.076496349687e+04  2.644671278966e+04  2.273458304119e+04
1.954349752908e+04  1.680032112209e+04  1.444218412726e+04  1.241504140604e+04  1.067243373686e+04
9.174423035938e+03  7.886677033340e+03  6.779682426302e+03  5.828068476394e+03  5.010025548360e+03
1.737988920100e+03  1.284332855871e+03  1.104060538508e+03  8.158747205330e+02  7.013564117662e+02
6.029121922103e+02  5.182858606802e+02  4.455379022877e+02  2.433020871700e+02  2.091515701348e+02
1.797945089525e+02  1.545580816278e+02  1.328639052196e+02  9.818329499070e+01  7.255514128762e+01
5.361653963401e+01  4.609078195788e+01  3.962135930423e+01  3.406000172766e+01  2.927925083995e+01
2.516953864546e+01  2.163667639887e+01  1.859969593339e+01  1.598899398582e+01  1.374473698894e+01
1.181548977143e+01  1.015703673713e+01  8.731368506527e+00  7.505810795983e+00  6.452275569743e+00
5.546617302183e+00  4.768079596776e+00  4.098819479081e+00  3.523498461194e+00  3.028931005477e+00
2.603782330822e+00  2.238308635635e+00  1.924133783786e+00  1.654057335509e+00  1.421889523591e+00
1.222309392724e+00  1.050742850800e+00  9.032578372386e-01  7.764742057598e-01  6.674862562538e-01
5.737961402745e-01  4.932566139141e-01  3.133421372728e-01  2.315524554696e-01  1.990511474577e-01
1.711118080085e-01  1.470941072881e-01  1.264475938317e-01  1.086990789815e-01  9.344179207682e-02
8.032605785014e-02  6.905128236880e-02  5.935906385039e-02  5.102727046220e-02
```

**My Input Values I used**

```
SKIP (for line 1 ... removed 45 Lines for better readablity
SKIP  to line 47)
4.163186002791e+04  3.578830331359e+04  3.076496349687e+04  2.644671278966e+04  2.273458304119e+04
1.954349752908e+04  1.680032112209e+04  1.444218412726e+04  1.241504140604e+04  1.067243373686e+04
9.174423035938e+03  7.886677033340e+03  6.779682426302e+03  5.828068476394e+03  5.010025548360e+03
1.737988920100e+03  1.284332855871e+03  1.104060538508e+03  8.158747205330e+02  7.013564117662e+02
6.029121922103e+02  5.182858606802e+02  4.455379022877e+02  2.433020871700e+02  2.091515701348e+02
1.797945089525e+02  1.545580816278e+02  1.328639052196e+02  9.818329499070e+01  7.255514128762e+01
5.361653963401e+01  4.609078195788e+01  3.962135930423e+01  3.406000172766e+01  2.927925083995e+01
2.516953864546e+01  2.163667639887e+01  1.859969593339e+01  1.598899398582e+01  1.374473698894e+01
1.181548977143e+01  1.015703673713e+01  8.731368506527e+00  7.505810795983e+00  6.452275569743e+00
5.546617302183e+00  4.768079596776e+00  4.098819479081e+00  3.523498461194e+00  3.028931005477e+00
2.603782330822e+00  2.238308635635e+00  1.924133783786e+00  1.654057335509e+00  1.421889523591e+00
1.222309392724e+00  1.050742850800e+00  9.032578372386e-01  7.764742057598e-01  6.674862562538e-01
5.737961402745e-01  4.932566139141e-01  3.133421372728e-01  2.315524554696e-01  1.990511474577e-01
1.711118080085e-01  1.470941072881e-01  1.264475938317e-01  1.086990789815e-01  9.344179207682e-02
8.032605785014e-02  6.905128236880e-02  5.935906385039e-02  5.102727046220e-02
```

Answer (score 0):

give a chance to linecache. and in case of large files, try generators.

```
import linecache
from sys import argv

def get_specific_lines(f, start, stop):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        yield linecache.getline(f, i)

script, f, s, e = argv

# check code if (f)ile exists, (s)tart and (e)nd are numeric.    

for line in get_specific_lines(f, int(s), int(e)):
    print line



$ wc -l asbc.txt 
197310 asbc.txt
$ python read.py asbc.txt 144322 144325
Bu yarım dəqiqə ərzində Qleb qabaqcadan dəqiq hesablanmış ləng hərəkətlə əlini qəbulediciyə uzatdı, diktora xırıldamağa imkan vermədən boynunu bururmuş kimi açarın dəstəyini burdu.

Onun azca bundan əvvəlki canlı sifəti yorğun, bozumtul rəng almışdı.

Pryançikovun başı isə başqa problemə qarışmışdı. Hansı gücləndirici kaskadı qoymaq lazım olduğu haqda fikirləşə-fikirləşə o, qayğısız zümzümə edirdi:
```